# class/ article / report not found error, texstudio

Tags: article, documentclass

i am new user of texstudio on mackbook. by typing \doucmentclass[option]{class}, replacing class with article it doesn't work, by placing curser on class, article it says class/article not found, same goes with title and author. by clicking on build and view, title, author not shown on plain page.
any guideline please ASAP

Comment: Have you added the commands `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`?... Is there anything between these commands (if exist) like some text or a `\maketitle`? The last one will print author, title and possibly date. Please share your code here in order to help us find if your problem is in the code or in your installation.

Comment: TeXstudio should have the option to start a "new from template" file from a basic article example using the first on the list hovering on article recognises it as article (I do not see your error message)

Comment: I only get class: article not found if there is a space or other character alongside article it must be {article} with no other characters